# Skipped 69 frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask, android-service

I get this error `The application may be doing too much work on its main thread` once in a while when the `MainActivity` is alive... i'm using threads, asyncTasks and services but still the error shows up..

This is the `MainActivity` code(with `NavigationDrawer` in it):

```
/*
* Declerations are here
*/

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //animAlpha = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.anim_alpha);
    //animRotate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.anim_rotate);

    i_music = new Intent(this,PlayMusicService.class);
    i_music.putExtra("action", "com.example.neotavraham.PLAY");
    startService(i_music);
    music_flag = 1;

    //background_music = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.yedid_nefesh);

    flipper = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.viewFlipper);
    flipper_thread = new Flipper(flipper);
    flipper_thread.execute();

    //background_music.start();

    Thread process_buttons = new Thread(){

        @Override
        public void run(){
            messages = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.messages_button);
            weekly_day_times = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.weekly_times_button);
            shabat_times = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.sat_times_button);
            events = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.events_button);
        }
    };

    Thread process_containers = new Thread(){

        @Override
        public void run(){
            mContainerView1 = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.add_shabat_container);
            mContainerView2 = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.add_weekly_container);
            mContainerView3 = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.add_messages_container);
            mContainerView4 = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.add_events_container);
            mContainerView5 = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.add_friday_night_container);
            mContainerView6 = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.add_friday_morning_container);
        }
    };

    Thread process_buttons_click_listener = new Thread(){

        @Override
        public void run(){
            messages.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);
            weekly_day_times.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);
            shabat_times.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);
            events.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);
        }
    };

    Thread process_nav_click_listener = new Thread(){

        @Override
        public void run(){
            findViewById(R.id.b_shabat_add).setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);
            findViewById(R.id.b_weekly_add).setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);
            findViewById(R.id.b_messages_add).setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);
            findViewById(R.id.b_events_add).setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);
            findViewById(R.id.b_friday_night_add).setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);
            findViewById(R.id.b_friday_morning_add).setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);
            findViewById(R.id.b_shabat_delete_all).setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);
            findViewById(R.id.b_friday_night_delete_all).setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);
            findViewById(R.id.b_friday_morning_delete_all).setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);
            findViewById(R.id.b_weekly_delete_all).setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);
            findViewById(R.id.b_messages_delete_all).setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);
            findViewById(R.id.b_events_delete_all).setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);

            findViewById(R.id.soundToggleButton).setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);
        }
    };


    process_buttons.start();
    process_containers.start();
    process_buttons_click_listener.start();
    process_nav_click_listener.start();

    IntializeNavDrawer();

}

 private void IntializeNavDrawer() {

    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);


    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
            GravityCompat.START);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            null, R.string.drawer_open,
            R.string.drawer_close) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
            // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to
            // onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
}

/*
 *more irrelevant funcs here..
 */
```

Also this is the service for the background music:

```
public class PlayMusicService extends Service {
public static final String ACTION_PLAY = "com.example.neotavraham.PLAY";
MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = null;

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    if (intent.getStringExtra("action").equals(ACTION_PLAY)) {
        mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.yedid_nefesh);
        mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true); // Set looping
        mMediaPlayer.start();
    }
    return flags;
}


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mMediaPlayer.stop();
    mMediaPlayer.release();
}
}
```

And this is the class of the flipper:

```
public class Flipper extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {

private final ViewFlipper vFlipper;

public Flipper(ViewFlipper vFlipper){
    this.vFlipper = vFlipper;
}
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    startFlipper();
    return null;
}

private void startFlipper() {

    vFlipper.setFlipInterval(5000);
    //flipper.setInAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,android.R.anim.fade_in));
    //flipper.setOutAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,android.R.anim.fade_out));
    vFlipper.startFlipping();
}
}
```

I test this code on my own phone, my galaxy s4, so it's not a problem of a slow emulator...

any ideas what should i do more?

Comment: your code is not going to work, because you can't interact with views in nonUI thread

Comment: @MickeyTin, and yet, it's working...

Comment: You should not be accessing UI elements on a different thread.  Android UI toolkit is not thread safe.  Even it is working for you right now, it can easily produce different results on a different device.  You should never call `findViewById(..)` or access any UI elements from a different thread.

Answer (score 1):

Android `Service` is running on `UI thread`, so you must create your own thread if you want to do too much work or use `IntentService` which by default runs on worker thread but it is doing one job at a time, so it has just one thread. if you want to have multiple threads you must use ordinary service and create your own threads. read: [Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

> First of all, like an Activity, all work in a Service is done in a
>   single thread by default—in fact, if you're running an activity and a
>   service from the same application, they use the same thread (the "main
>   thread") by default. Therefore, services need to process incoming
>   intents quickly and never perform lengthy computations when responding
>   to them. If any heavy work or blocking calls are expected, you must do
>   those tasks asynchronously: either from another thread you implement
>   yourself, or using the framework's many facilities for asynchronous
>   processing.

[Link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html#mpandservices)

Comment: So can u tell me what exactly is not good? the music service? the use of AsyncTask for the flipper or the regular threads in onCreate()?

Comment: Create your mMediaPlayer on a seperate thread inside your service or use async call of that class.